# Tag synonym request for gameloop and game-loop

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

[Gameloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gameloop) and [game-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-loop) tags are obviously synonyms but I can't declare them as synonyms myself so asking for help of more reputable people!

Comment: _"Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag."_ Aww shoot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done. There was a tag wiki that was lost in the merge and I restored its excerpt; for some reason, the main wiki content was extremely poorly-written compared to the excerpt, to the point where I was fine with it being lost in the merge.