# Tag names and gratuitous hyphens—TrueType

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There is a standard for fonts named [TrueType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType). There is no space, no hyphen, the same as with, say, JavaScript.

However, there is a tag [true-type-fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/true-type-fonts) instead of [truetype-fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truetype-fonts).

Is the former tag name in error? If so, should it be changed to the latter?

(Incidentally, the tag also exists on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tags), where the unhyphenated [truetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truetype) tag also [exists](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/truetype) and has more than zero questions.)

Comment: FWIW, there's [tag:truetype] (without hyphens) that is synonymized to [tag:true-type-fonts] (with hyphens) (ref: [tag synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/true-type-fonts/synonyms))

Comment: Nope, just users naming tags how they see fit (often, erroneously). Agreed there is no reason for hyphenation here as it should denote word separation (like [tag:version-control] or [tag:google-analytics-api]).

Comment: @AndrewT. I intended the truetype tag to link to the SO one so that people can see that there are no SO truetype-tagged questions. I'm just glad there is no java-script tag to link to for the counter-example ;)

Comment: @OlegValter Although "retag-request" *appears* to be a correct tag, its info says it is for "requests to replace one tag with another existing tag." Maybe its purpose could be debated in a new question to include renaming. I've left it as I agree with the latter.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - yeah, I know, just it is usually added to tag rename questions. Agreed that we should either have a tag for renaming or expand the definition of this one. Been thinking about launching a request for that for a while.

Comment: Anyways, now we just need a mod to notice as far as I recall - don't think anyone would object to this renaming (only concern is the last [meta-tag:status-completed] on retag-requests is from March, 14th). Guess I was wrong about the latter

Comment: @OlegValter It looks like I just "accidentally" created a tag named tag-rename. Let's see if this question can get *more* downvotes (why, oh why, oh why?) just for that :)

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I suggest it be [made a synonym](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/retag-request/synonyms) of the [retag-request] then - low-hassle solution to both problems (if 4 others agree that is). Hope the renaming of the TTF tag goes well - an obvious spelling issue

Comment: If the downvoter would be so bold as to say why a mis-spelling as a tag is a good idea, I am sure we would all be interested to hear more.

Comment: I believe that the mere existence of this tag is suspect. In what context you program with truetype fonts? Usually in the context of something bigger: a library, framework or language. Those have tag already. Just use those instead.

Comment: @Braiam - https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/

Comment: I believe that the mere existence of this tag is suspect.  In what context in a program would you refer to a [Font](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Gr%C3%B6tlingbo_kyrka_dopfunt.jpg/800px-Gr%C3%B6tlingbo_kyrka_dopfunt.jpg)?  Surely the question is off-topic.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reversed the synonym, which didn't seem to have much of an effect on either [true-type-fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/true-type-fonts) or [ttf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ttf) still mapping to the hyphenated tag, so I explicitly performed a merge, and that seems to have sorted it.

> FWIW, there's truetype (without hyphens) that is synonymized to true-type-fonts (with hyphens) (ref: tag synonym page) – Andrew T.

This comes from [ttf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ttf) originally being a synonym of [true-type-fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/true-type-fonts) back in 2010. The latter tag, hyphens and all, was created back in 2008. [truetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truetype) was added [shortly after](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60482/tag-synonym-proposal-truetype-ttf-on-stack-overflow-is-stuck).

Truthfully, I should've changed it the first time I encountered it after becoming a mod (before, I didn't pay much attention to tag synonyms), considering I took my [hyphens](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261333/tag-synonym-request-for-gameloop-and-game-loop/261337#261337) in [tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151696/make-quirksmode-a-tag-synonym-of-quirks-mode/151697#151697) [very](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113627/hyphenate-mediaqueries-as-media-queries) [seriously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188990/merge-isolatedstorage-and-isolated-storage-tags/189008#189008). (I even found a [gatekeeping comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271068/what-should-we-do-with-iphone6-and-iphone6/271074#271074), ew, much cringe, but to be fair, that's Apple. Told y'all I wasn't always the good moderator I strive to be today.)

> Anyways, now we just need a mod to notice – Oleg Valter

Yeah, I'm surprised no one else paid attention to this in the last 16 hours. I guess it's the weekend. I had just ended my Stack session for the night, been to bed, then been to church. Then I saw this.

> If the downvoter would be so bold as to say why a **mis-spelling** as a tag is a good idea, I am sure we would all be interested to hear more. – Andrew Morton

I see what you did there.

> In what context you program with truetype fonts? – Braiam

Font files *are* programs. They're often used as complete packages for typesetting (typography, cosmetic) reasons, yes, but they are in fact programs in their own right. And you *can* write a font using just instructions, even though it's strongly recommended to use font authoring software like FontLab, Glyphs or FontCreator.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any point to it being mentioned in the Teacher's Lounge so other sites with the same misspelling can make the correction? I've already [asked on Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14443/tag-rename-request-for-spelling-of-truetype): I imagine it is used on some other sites too.